# What's the equivalent of "killall gnome-panel" when using Unity?

Tags: 10.10, unity, gnome-panel

Sometimes icons don't draw successfully in the GNOME panel and a `killall gnome-panel` is a good quick fix. Is there an equivalent in Unity?
I'm specifically having issues with the Dropbox icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`killall mutter` will restart the window manager, which includes Unity and its components (panel, sidebar, etc). The screen will flicker as it restarts, but your windows and applications should stay open afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, though I had to restart mutter manually.

Comment: Really? That's odd, it should have respawned on its own.